# Why doesn't $f(z)=\sqrt z$ work as a counterexample to If $f(z)$ is not an entire function, then $g(z) = f^2(z)$ cannot be an entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

We have a statement “If $f(z)$ is not an entire function, then $g(z) = f^2(z)$ cannot be an entire function.”.

Two students and a professor had the following conversation:

A: The statement is false. I can give a counter-example. Let $f(z) = \sqrt z$, assuming that it is a branch that takes −1 to i. Then it is not analytic on the branch cut, but $g(z) = f ^2(z) = z$ is obviously an entire function.

B: I think this is not a counter-example, so we cannot conclude the statement is false yet.

Professor: Good! B is correct. The statement is false.

Now I give you an assignment:

(a) Show that student A’s example does not work as a counter-example.

Why doesn't student A's example work as a counter example? I don't understand what is wrong with the statement that it'd be incorrect

Also I'm not exactly clear on what $f^2(z)$ means is it $f(f(z))$ or $[f(z)]^2$

This is a bit different from my previous question as previously I was asking about why it wasn't analytic on the branch cut, now I'm trying to understand why the counterexample: $f(z)=\sqrt z$ isn't right.
I know $f(z)$ is not analytic on the branch -1 to i therefore not entire, but $f^2(z)=z$ is clearly analytic, and therefore entire so it should work as a counterexample however the question states it doesn't. I don't understand why it doesn't work as a counter example. No matter how I look at it $z$ is obviously entire and $\sqrt z$ isn't so shouldn't it work as a proper counter example.

Comment: $f^2(z)=f(z)\times f(z)$.  Neither of you suggestions.

Comment: Didn’t you already ask this question?

Comment: Is the domain of $f^2$ magically larger than the domain of $f$? Lots of sloppiness here.

Comment: $f$ need not be analytic, nor even continuous, as the problem is stated, so $f$ can be defined on the cut. @TedShifrin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disproving the statement "If $f(z)$ is not an entire function, then $g(z) = f^2(z)$ is not entire.”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155564/disproving-the-statement-if-fz-is-not-an-entire-function-then-gz-f2) which is your question that you accepted an answer to.  What has changed?

Comment: Oh, I see, some people are reading $f^2(z)$ as $f(f(z))?$